# How to union multiple tables combining columns with same name

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the following tables:

```sql
Table B                       Table C
ID    PROP_A    PROB_B        ID    PROP_A    PROP_C
-----------------------       -----------------------
1     V1        V1            1     V2        V2
2     V2        V2            2     V3        V3
3     V3        V3            3     V4        V4
```

I would like to unioun those tables to obtain the following result:

```sql
Table B+C
ID    TABLE_NAME    PROP_A    PROP_B    PROP_C
-----------------------------------------------------
1     B             V1        V1        null
2     B             V2        V2        null
3     B             V3        V3        null
1     C             V2        null      V2
2     C             V3        null      V3
3     C             V4        null      V4
```

I'm looking for a solution that is agnostic to the database technology (standard SQL). However, in case of technology dependent SQL, I would to like known how to do it in Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like `union all`:

```
select id, 'B' as table_name, prop_a, prop_b, null as prop_c
from b
union all
select id, 'C' as table_name, prop_a, null as prop_b, prop_c
from c;
```

Comment: That's right, I didn't know about the `null as prop_c`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is odd that you want the `TABLE_NAME` column in the output as the second column, not the first. Is that important?

If it's not - if having it as the first column is OK - then there is a solution that does not require you to know the number and name of the **columns** of the two tables in advance. It uses `natural full outer join` which is in the standard.

I don't have your tables, so I tested with the `EMP` and `DEPT` tables in the `SCOTT` schema. Change the table names as needed. The only constraint is that the table names **must** be different; that is what causes the natural full outer join to become the union you desire.

```
select *
from   (select 'EMP'  as table_name, e.* from scott.emp  e)
       natural full outer join
       (select 'DEPT' as table_name, d.* from scott.dept d)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to have all columns in both Selects. You can use static values, like this:

```
SELECT b.ID, 'B' AS TABLE_NAME, b.PROP_A, b.PROP_B, NULL AS PROP_C
FROM b
UNION ALL
SELECT c.ID, 'C' AS TABLE_NAME, c.PROP_A, NULL AS PROP_B, c.PROP_C
FROM c
```